# How to make dictionary multiplication faster?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, optimization, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to make function `f()` faster. I run it hundreds of millions of times, so any speed increase would be appreciated. The IDs of dictionary `a` and `b` are same across runs, `w` is a constant. The keys are integers; the keys are not evenly distributed in general.

Also, the function is in a class object. So f is f(self), and the variables are self.w, self.ID, self.a, and self.b

```
w = 10.25
ID = range(10)
a = {}
b = {}

for i in ID:
    a[i] = random.uniform(0,1)
    b[i] = random.uniform(0,1)

def f():
    for i in ID:
        a[i] = b[i] * w

t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(1000000):
    f()
t1 = time.time()
print t1-t0
```

Comment: What do your keys represent? (Are they integers, evenly distributed, …?)

Comment: They are integers, not evenly distributed....

Comment: In what range? What do they represent?

Comment: Why are you using `dict`s instead of `list`s (or even better: `numpy` arrays, for which you can broadcast multiplication)?

Comment: Several easy things: Use `list`s instead of `dict`s for `a` and `b`. Secondly, get rid of the `for` loop in `f()` and write out the 10 slightly different multiplications. Lastly, also in `f()`, copy the value of `w` into a local variable and use that instead of the global.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. f and the variables are a part of a class object. I need to use dictionary for other reasons in the code, so I can't use lists.. 

@Ryan the indexes represent other instances of the class.

Comment: @martineau can you please explain what you mean by "get rid of the for loop in f() and write out the 10 slightly different multiplications"... Thanks

Comment: @user58925: Btw, if you need dictionary in another part of the code, you can still have a dictionary that holds the mapping from an integer to *the index of that integer in the numpy array*. Then use a numpy array to do the multiplication itself. Numpy broadcast multiplication might be using some optimization, which might be faster than a self-implemented loop.

Comment: @user58925  Thanks. What you say  sounds useful for several purposes. Can you please give an example?

Comment: @user58925 Is the following what you mean, this seems to increase time necessary to perform the computation..

def h(a, b ,w):
    z = w * np.array(b.values())
    a = dict(zip(a.keys(), z))

Comment: What I meant by get rid of the `for` loop was replace it with a series of statements with hardcoded indices that will do the same thing. i.e. `a[0] = b[0] * w`, `a[1] = b[1] * w`, `a[2] = b[2] * w`, etc, BTW, it doesn't do anything useful to put "@user58925" in your own comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a nice speed-up by localizing the variables in *f()*:

```
def f(ID=ID, a=a, b=b, w=w):
    for i in ID:
        a[i] = b[i] * w
```

Some folks don't like localizing in that way, so you can also build a closure which will give you a speed-up of global variable access:

```
def make_f(a, b, w, ID):
    def f():
        for i in ID:
            a[i] = b[i] * w
    return f

f = make_f(a, b, w, ID)
```

See [this analysis](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577834) of which types of variable access are fastest.

Algorithmically, there is not much else that can be done.  The looping over *ID* is fast because it just increments reference counts for existing integers.  The hashing of the integers is practically instant because the hash of an int is the int itself.  Dict lookups themselves are already highly optimized.  Likewise, there is no short-cut for multiplying by a constant.

Comment: The function and the variables are a part of the class object. So essentially f is f(self), and the objects are self.w, self.a, self.b, and self.ID;

would localizing as you suggest still help?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if a function is in a class.  Localized variable access and nested scope access are always faster than global variable access.

Comment: Thanks. Its about 30-40% faster. The code is perhaps not as clean because  I have to pass class variables as arguments into class functions. But considerable gain.